# How to randomly generate a nonnegative orthogonal matrix in numpy?

Tags: numpy, matrix

Is there any function that can randomly generate a nonnegative orthogonal matrix in numpy or in other python libraries? Here the nonnegative means all the elements in that orthogonal matrix must be nonnegative.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it true that given a nonnegative orthogonal matrix in R^(nxn), `A`, then `A` is one of the n! permutation matrices of order n ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322514/nonnegative-orthogonal-matrices))?  If so, then your task reduces to just computing a random permutation matrix.  That's easy:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: def rand_perm_mat(N):
            I = np.eye(N)
            p = np.random.permutation(np.arange(N))
            return I[p]
In [3]: A = rand_perm_mat(5)
In [4]: A
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
In [5]: A.dot(A.T)
Out[5]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Thanks! What you are talking about is to generate an orthogonal matrix with only 0 or 1 as entries. But what if the entries are nonnegative real numbers?

Comment: By the post linked in my answer, I think that if an orthogonal matrix has all nonnegative values, then it can be proven it is a binary orthogonal matrix.  Edit: Thinking about the 2D/3D cases, the only nonnegative elements of SO(2) or SO(3) are binary (0s and 1s).  Once any element is nonbinary, then the matrix has negative elements.

Comment: One more question, if the matrix A is not square, how can I generate one?

Comment: @Isaiah what exactly is your question?  How to generate a semi-orthogonal matrix?

Comment: Let me explain this in a formal way. I need a randomly generated matrix A (N*M and N > M) such that A^T * A = I and A >= 0. Is this clear?

Comment: @Isaiah  I am pretty sure that the only nonnegative (semi-)orthogonal matrices of shape NxM (N > M) are those with 1.) a square block of size n <= M where that block is a permutation matrix of order n, and 2.) zeros everywhere else.  If you remove the nonnegative constraint, then there are many others, but the nonnegative constraint is very restrictive.